# Join Dictionary<int, string> and List<MyClass> error (type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage)

Tags: c#, list, join, dictionary, inferred-type

I´m trying to join a `Dictionary<int, string>` and `List<MyClass>` but it throws an error

> *"type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage".*

But it seems to me all the arguments are perfectly defined...

```
class Row
{
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string[] data { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<int, string> devices = new Dictionary<int,string>();
List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();

rows = rows.Join(devices, row => row.data[0], device => device.Key, (row, device) => { row.data[1] = device.Value; return row; }).ToList();
```

`row` is a `Row`, `device` is a `pair<int,string>`, `device.Key` is an `int`, and `device.Value` is a k. What is the problem? I know it must be a silly thing, but I´m stuck with this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row.data[0]` is a string, but `device.Key` is an integer, so the key types don't match.

Comment: A silly thing indeed. I needed to convert row.data[0] to int Convert.ToInt32(row.data[0])

Comment: Even if the compiler can infer the type arguments (or as in your case, it can't), it helps to write them down anyway if you're not sure what's happening:

rows.Join<Row, KeyValuePair<int, string>, int, string>(...)

Comment: Although VS complained about it couldn´t inferring type argument, the problem was not about inferring type argument, but that the join on need to have same type arguments, it´s not smart enough to cast an int to string or viceversa. I wrote down the type arguments but didn´t achieve anything...

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `device => device.Key` is an `int` where as `row.data[0]` is a `string`. They are both of the generic type `TKey` and need to be consistent. It can be fixed by calling `ToString()` on `device.Key`.

```
rows = rows.Join(devices, row => row.data[0], device => device.Key.ToString(), (row, device) => { row.data[1] = device.Value; return row; }).ToList();
```